# ¿Cómo enviar un nested Object por POST en body con Retrofit2 (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, android-studio, json, api, kotlin

Tengo duda como enviar un nested Object por medio del body y una petición POST con Kotlin, no me queda muy claro como enviar los valores por body o como definirlos para ser enviados, o por otro lado si está mal la forma en que envío los datos, ya que me esta saltando error 500 en RETROFIT, eso indica que al parecer estoy realizando mal la llamada, por lo tanto no devuelve nada,

Mi código es el siguiente

APIService

```
interface APIService {
    // ...
    @Headers(
        "Authorization: Bearer 8176348172-63487623548-738726-346678",
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
    )
    @POST("/v2/ruta")
    suspend fun getNestedData(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Response<ResponseBody>

    // ...
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "campo1": "valor",
  "campo2": {
    "campo3": "valor2",
    "campo4": "valor3"
  },
  "campo5": {
    "campo6": "valor4",
    "campo7": {
      "campo8": "valor5"
    }
  }
}
```

Clase(Se quiere enviar por body esos campos serializados como Objeto pero ya con valores definidos):

```
data class example(
    @SerializedName("campoPrincipal") val campo1: String,
    val campo2: Campo2,
    val campo5: Campo5
)

data class Campo2(
    val campo3: String,
    val campo4: String
)

data class Campo5(
    val campo6: String,
    val campo7: Campo7
)

data class Campo7(
    @SerializedName("campoSecundario") val campo8: String
)
```

MainActivity (no estoy seguro si estoy enviando un Json Object correctamente para modificar campos con el método POST):

```
@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            fun parseJSON() {
                // Create Retrofit
                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://abcdefghi")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()

                // Create Service
                val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)


                // Create JSON using JSONObject

                val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                jsonObject.put( "campoPrincipal", "hola1") //No se como se envia serializado
                jsonObject.put( "campoSecundario", "hola1")

                // Convert JSONObject to String
                val jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString()

                val requestBody = 
               jsonObjectString.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())


                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

                    // Do the POST request and get response
                    val response = service.getNestedData(requestBody)


                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        // Do the POST request and get response
                        val response = service.getNestedData(requestBody)

                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful) {

                                // Convert raw JSON to pretty JSON using GSON library
                                val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                                val prettyJson = gson.toJson(
                                    JsonParser.parseString(
                                        response.body()?.string() 
                                    )
                                )

                                Log.d("Pretty Printed JSON :", 
                                response.body().toString())

                            } else {

                                Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            parseJSON()
```

Comment: No me queda claro que quieres hacer. Por qué no creas la instancia de `example` directamente? Y estás seguro que no devuelve nada? Si sólo imprimes el código de respuesta podrías estar ignorando un mensaje de error.

Comment: Hola mucho gusto, solo pretendo enviar partes de un nested Object con valores por el body, ejemplo, tengo mi json como el de arriba, puedo modificar valores enviando esa parte del json por body ejemplo el valor 2:  `{
  "campo2": {
    "campo3": "valor2modificado"}}` entonces lo unico es saber como enviar ese nested Object por body, mi duda es como darle valor a los campos y como enviarlos por post ya que al parecer mi peticion está mal

Comment: Creo que entendí pero para mayor claridad deberías agregar en la pregunta un ejemplo del json que quieres enviar. Menciona que campos son opcionales y cuales obligatorios.

Comment: Pues practicamente todos serian valores modificables que podria enviar o no por el body, se me ocurre una especie de settings donde pueda modificar el valor que quiera y mandarlo como Objeto

Comment: Es decir que puedes enviar cualquier JSON? Entonces para que tienes las clases? No creo que esa sea la mejor forma de hacerlo pero no das detalles suficientes para poder ofrecerte otras alternativas. Sería más fácil si supieramos que API intentas usar. Si realmente necesitas hacerlo de esa manera debes anidar los jsonObjet por ejemplo `val campo2 = JSONObject(); campo2.put("campo3", "valor3Modificado"); jsonObject.put("campo2", campo2)`

Comment: y no puedes decir "*No se como se envia serializado*" porque tienes la variable `jsonObjectString` que te muestra exactamente como queda serializado. Además puedes ver la petición completa en el [profiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n9sBgds-Hs&t=185) de android studio. Lee la [documentación sobre cómo hacer debug](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pues si es por eso, lo que escribi que no puedo hacer la llamada y no se como enviar la información así, he buscado y no encuentro muchos ejemplos sobre eso, voy a checar esos links que me comentas muchas gracias.

Comment: Para enviar un body, en este caso, el parámetro que recibe la interfaz debe ser el data class example y ya está, no tienes que crear ningún request body.

Comment: Hola Manuel, muchisisimas gracias por la respuesta, una pregunta, si puedo enviar el data class sin meterle un request body, como podria ponerle valores a mi clase en el activity? Eso no logro entenderlo, Y en caso de tenerlos ya, se envia de la misma forma? He visto ejemplos en java pero en Kotlin veo algo limitada la info, te agradezco bastante